# Percentage of team with a certain amount of entries

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> df
    teams people entries
1  A Team   6fd1      49
2  A Team   1df5       4
3  A Team   2hgt      19
4  A Team   8akt       4
5  A Team   sdf9      19
6  B Team   asc1      42
7  B Team   abm8      32
8  B Team   plo9      38
9  B Team   90la       5
10 B Team   8uil      23

> dput(df)
structure(list(teams = c("A Team", "A Team", "A Team", "A Team", 
"A Team", "B Team", "B Team", "B Team", "B Team", "B Team"), 
    people = c("6fd1", "1df5", "2hgt", "8akt", "sdf9", "asc1", 
    "abm8", "plo9", "90la", "8uil"), entries = c(49, 4, 19, 4, 
    19, 42, 32, 38, 5, 23)), .Names = c("teams", "people", "entries"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am able to get a percentage of the teams that have above 75% by doing this, albeit messy and probably not the best way:

```
#  sorted df and added cumulative percentage/sum and row number per team

> df
    teams people entries cumulative_sum cumulative_perc number
1  A Team   6fd1      49             49        51.57895      1
3  A Team   2hgt      19             68        71.57895      2
5  A Team   sdf9      19             87        91.57895      3
2  A Team   1df5       4             91        95.78947      4
4  A Team   8akt       4             95       100.00000      5
7  B Team   abm8      89             89        45.17766      1
6  B Team   asc1      42            131        66.49746      2
8  B Team   plo9      38            169        85.78680      3
10 B Team   8uil      23            192        97.46193      4
9  B Team   90la       5            197       100.00000      5

#  from this view, each team has 3/5 people (60%) reaching the minimum 75% 
#  entries, and using ddply, we can get that

ddply(df, 'teams', summarise,
      marker = min(which(cumulative_perc > 75)),
      total = NROW(teams),
      seventyfive = marker/total)

   teams marker total seventyfive
1 A Team      3     5       0.6
2 B Team      3     5       0.6
```

and while that works, I want to take into account only the percentage of entries of the third person that was actually 75% of the teams entries. For example, for A Team, 75% of their entries is 72 (rounded up), which would mean that we are only looking at 4 of the 19 entries for the third person, giving that team 2.21/5 instead of 3/5.

Comment: ...so what is the expected output? I really don't understand what you mean by `third person`?

Comment: ...4 of which 19 entries? Why 2.21/5? So many questions...

Comment: in the example, after ordering, 3 is the minimum of people with 75% of the teams entries. but for both teams, that third observation has a cumulative percentage that is not exactly 75% at that point (for example, 91.58 for team A, 85.78 for team B). I said third person just for this example, it could be the 4th ordered person, 5th, so on. and 2.21/5 is essentially the expected output. you get 2 full peoples work to take you to 71.58% cumulative percentage, but I only want to take .21% or (4 of the total 19 entries) from the third observation as that will equal 75% (or 72 entries), exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(teams) %>% 
  summarise(seventyfive = {
    tmp1 <- ceiling(0.75 * sum(entries)); tmp2 <- sum(cumsum(entries) < tmp1)
    tmp2 + (tmp1 - sum(entries[1:tmp2])) / entries[tmp2 + 1]
  })
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   teams  seventyfive
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 A Team        2.21
# 2 B Team        2.78
```

`tmp1` is the 75% of entries, while `tmp2` is the maximal number of entries still giving the cumulative percentage lower than 75%. The final line then directly computes the desired quantity.

Comment: I get `3` and `2.28` for `A` and `B` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

`lead()` gives you the next rows' variable in your current group.

Below approach filters for the one row that is a fraction (0-1) of the next variable's entries away from the minimum amount of entries.

```
df %>%
    group_by(teams) %>%
    arrange(teams, -entries) %>%
    mutate(delta = (ceiling(0.75 * sum(entries)) - cumsum(entries)) / lead(entries),
           marker = row_number() + delta) %>%
    filter(delta >= 0 & delta <= 1) %>%
    select(teams, marker)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   teams [2]
  teams  marker
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A Team   2.21
2 B Team   2.78
```